# slider toggle when user click on the frontview SWRevealViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, slider

Hi I am using SWRevealViewController library for sliding menu in my iphone app and already I have implemented it, but there's a problem, after the menu appears and user click on the front view the menu doesn't toggle like in facebook !
Scenario: 
-User pressed or swipped on the front view.
-the menu appears.
-when user click on the front view again the menu doesn't disappear it still and that's strange!

How can I make the view toggle again, Thank you

Comment: did you manage to resolve this?